# How to aggregateByKey with custom class for frequency distribution?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying to create a frequency distribution.

My data is in the following pattern `(ColumnIndex, (Value, countOfValue))` of type `(Int, (Any, Long))`. For instance, `(1, (A, 10))` means for column index 1, there are 10 A's.

My goal is to get the top 100 values for all my index's or Keys.

Right away I can make it less compute intensive for my workload by doing an initial filter:

```
val freqNumDist = numRDD.filter(x => x._2._2 > 1)
```

Now I found an interesting example of a class, here which seems to fit my use case:

```
class TopNList (val maxSize:Int) extends Serializable {
  val topNCountsForColumnArray = new mutable.ArrayBuffer[(Any, Long)]
  var lowestColumnCountIndex:Int = -1
  var lowestValue = Long.MaxValue

  def add(newValue:Any, newCount:Long): Unit = {
    if (topNCountsForColumnArray.length < maxSize -1) {
      topNCountsForColumnArray += ((newValue, newCount))
    } else if (topNCountsForColumnArray.length == maxSize) {
      updateLowestValue
    } else {
      if (newCount > lowestValue) {
        topNCountsForColumnArray.insert(lowestColumnCountIndex, (newValue, newCount))
        updateLowestValue
      }
    }
  }

  def updateLowestValue: Unit = {
    var index = 0

    topNCountsForColumnArray.foreach{ r =>
      if (r._2 < lowestValue) {
        lowestValue = r._2
        lowestColumnCountIndex = index
      }
      index+=1
    }
  }
}
```

So Now What I was thinking was putting together an `aggregateByKey` to use this class in order to get my top 100 values! The problem is that I am unsure of how to use this class in `aggregateByKey` in order to accomplish this goal.

```
  val initFreq:TopNList = new TopNList(100)

  def freqSeq(u: (TopNList), v:(Double, Long)) = (
    u.add(v._1, v._2)
    )

  def freqComb(u1: TopNList, u2: TopNList) = (
    u2.topNCountsForColumnArray.foreach(r => u1.add(r._1, r._2))
    )
val freqNumDist = numRDD.filter(x => x._2._2 > 1).aggregateByKey(initFreq)(freqSeq, freqComb)
```

The obvious problem is that nothing is returned by the functions I am using. So I am wondering how to modify this class or do I need to think about this in a whole new light and just cherry pick some of the functions out of this class and add them to the functions I am using for the aggregateByKey?

I'm either thinking about classes wrong or the entire `aggregateByKey` or both!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your projections implementations (**freqSeq**, **freqComb**) return **Unit** while you expect them to return **TopNList**

If intentially keep the style of your solution, the relevant impl should be

```
def freqSeq(u: TopNList, v:(Any, Long)) : TopNList = {
  u.add(v._1, v._2) // operation gives void result (Unit)
  u                 // this one of TopNList type 
}

def freqComb(u1: TopNList, u2: TopNList) : TopNList = {
  u2.topNCountsForColumnArray.foreach (r => u1.add (r._1, r._2) )
  u1
}
```

Just take a look on **aggregateByKey** signature of **PairRDDFunctions**, what does it expect for

```
def aggregateByKey[U](zeroValue : U)(seqOp : scala.Function2[U, V, U], combOp : scala.Function2[U, U, U])(implicit evidence$3 : scala.reflect.ClassTag[U]) : org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[scala.Tuple2[K, U]] = { /* compiled code */ }
```